# Unit test fails after adding a new test

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I am currently working on an Ionic (v3) app and we have several tests to test services, pages and components.

Everything was working fine until I added a new test for a component.

Both tests run fine individually (if started with `fdescribe`, or if I comment one of them out).

The tests look like this:

verify-key.spec.ts

```
describe('Component: VerifyKey', () => {

  let component: VerifyKeyComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<VerifyKeyComponent>

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [VerifyKeyComponent],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(VerifyKeyComponent)
      ]
    })

    // create component and test fixture
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VerifyKeyComponent)

    // get test component from the fixture
    component = fixture.componentInstance
  })
  ...
})
```

wallet-select-coins.spec.ts

```
describe('Wallet-Select-Coin Component', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WalletSelectCoinsPage>
  let component: WalletSelectCoinsPage

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [WalletSelectCoinsPage],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(WalletSelectCoinsPage),
        ComponentsModule,
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
          name: '__airgap_storage',
          driverOrder: ['localstorage']
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        SecretsProvider,
        {
          provide: SecureStorageService,
          useFactory: SecureStorageFactory,
          deps: [Platform]
        },
        { provide: NavController, useClass: NavControllerMock },
        { provide: NavParams, useClass: NavParamsMock },
        { provide: StatusBar, useClass: StatusBarMock },
        { provide: SplashScreen, useClass: SplashScreenMock },
        { provide: Platform, useClass: PlatformMock }
      ]
    })
  }))

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WalletSelectCoinsPage)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })

  it('should not show hd-wallet dropdown if currency does not support it', () => {
    let el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement
    let ethereumRadio = el.querySelector('#eth')

    // click on ethereum
    ethereumRadio.click()
    fixture.detectChanges()
    console.log(component.selectedProtocol)
    expect(component.selectedProtocol).toBeDefined() // This fails
    expect(component.selectedProtocol.identifier).toEqual('eth')

    // eth should not show hd wallets
    let hdWalletSelector = el.querySelector('#wallet-type-selector')
    expect(hdWalletSelector).toBeFalsy()
  })

})
```

If both tests are enabled, the second one fails at the line `expect(component.selectedProtocol).toBeDefined()` with the error `Expected undefined to be defined.`

If I comment out the line `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VerifyKeyComponent)` from the first file, then the  second test runs without any issues.

My first idea was that the TestBed somehow gets modified in the first test. So I tried adding `TestBed.resetTestingModule()` after the first test, but that didn't change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When writing tests its best practice to clean up everything after every test so that all test can run in random order without effecting any other test.

I would suggest to introduce a `afterEach()` or `afterAll()` in every test which clears any data which is produced. Because most test environments run all tests in the same context.

And why would you like that your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` to be created async()? Your test will run but the async part will probably never get called before the `it(..`

Hope these ideas will help :)

Comment: Removing `async` doesn't change anything. Both tests together still fail.

I know that we should clean up everything that happened. But I don't know **what**. I tried resetting the TestBed and the fixture, but it didn't help. It's like there is something that doesn't get cleaned up, but I don't know what it is...

Comment: @Andreas Gassmann: Have you tried changing the execution order of your tests, possibly also against other tests from the test suite?